# stopPropagation for bootstrap-select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I have a table that highlights the row when the row is clicked. I placed Bootstrap-select by silvio moreto in a row but when I select the drop down, the row highlight is executed. How can I avoid this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjmf8qqt/ (not sure why row highlight is not working here but it works well locally)

When I do the following, the dropdown breaks:

```
$('.bootstrap-select').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Fiddle is not working. check errors in console

Comment: Do you really want to use bootstrap select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $( '#resultTable' ).delegate( 'tr', 'click', function ( e ) {
        if ( $( e.target ).is( 'tr' ) || $( e.target ).is( 'td' )) {
            $(this).toggleClass('warning');
            var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
            $(checkbox).prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
        } else if($(e.target).is( ':checkbox' )) {
            $(e.target).closest('tr').toggleClass('warning');
        }else {
                console.log("select " +e.target);
        }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikpandey/xjmf8qqt/4/) for the same. You need to ensure that you have a single event handler for all the events in your table. So you need to check the target on which the click event happened, because you are using bootstrap select, you can click on either the span or the button it creates. If the click is not on either, then you highlight the row.

EDIT - Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikpandey/xjmf8qqt/6/). Everything works here.

Comment: P.S - The fiddle wasn't working because you were using an old version of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks but selecting a value from the dropdown still toggles the row highlight. Also, the row highlight does not work anymore for newly added rows when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: First one might be because it would redraw the table again which might trigger that event. I will look into it

Comment: Could you check the updated fiddle and let me know if it helped